# How to set up restart of cluster to be graceful and control how shards are allocated in elasticsearch6.4.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elk

I want to set up the restart job to be a graceful restart where a node will not begin to restart until the previous node is back up and operational.
Only once a the first node is back up and working will the second node restart and so on until it's through all the nodes.

Also,I want to control how soon to start reallocating shards if we loose a node. I need to set it to 5 min.

Ant suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This process is documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-cluster.html)